# after power outage, monitor won't turn on

Tags: display

I had a power outage in my apartment today during a Windows 7 SP1 update. I installed SP1 and it told me to restart so I did and that's when the power outage happened. After the power came back on, I started the computer and it looks like the computer is running normally but my monitor is not getting a signal. I am using a Wacom Cintiq 21UX. I tried unplugging all the cords and plugs in the power strip and turning it back on. I also tried a strange method I read in another thread of removing the power cord, holding the on button for 30 seconds, putting the power cord back in, and turning it on. Still no dice. How can I get my monitor to turn on? please help..

Comment: Are you sure it was just an outage and not a surge?

Comment: @Ignacio I am not sure. It was just an assumption.

Comment: is the diode of the monitor glowing? If it is not maybe there is a fuse inside of the monitor which broke due to a spike in the current. Just look for thing which looks like a big plastic screw. Or a small plate you could open. If there is nothing like that open up the monitor and take a look at the part where the cables goes into the monitor. If there is a fuse it should be close to that. Normally you could easily see if the fuse is broken, if the fuse is black or the small wire is melted like the one in a light bulb.

Comment: @Darokthar There is an orange light which signifies that there is no signal in the monitor. Is that the diode? Usually, the light turns blue when the monitor gets a signal.

Comment: Yes, that is the diode. This means the monitor has power and the fuse is ok. Thus something in the monitor itself is broken or the graphic card. You would have to follow Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams solution then... Couldn't you connect the monitor to the old dell laptop? If it works there your graphic card will probably have some failure. Look for capacitors on the graphic card. If they have the form of a barrel or a convex top and are not formed like a cylinder it is a good sign for a broken capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that a surge immediately preceding or following the outage damaged your video card or monitor. Examine the video card for any visible damage, and try replacing it with another (or try the monitor on another machine) to verify that it isn't your monitor.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any visible damage on the video card or any other parts for that matter. Unfortunately, I don't have another video card nor do I have a separate machine (other than an old Dell laptop) to test the monitor on.

Comment: Also, I should mention that I have all my cords plugged into a surge protector so even if there was a surge, I don't think it would have messed anything up, right?

Comment: Most surge protectors are sketchy at best.

Comment: I have another laptop with the ac adaptor connected directly to an outlet in the wall and it's working fine. Also, the light in my monitor is on (orange signifying 'no signal'). Would this mean that a surge wasn't the culprit?

Comment: No, those are not indicative of anything on their own.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the exact same problem. All we did is repeatedly hit the f8 button while the computer was booting up, this took us to a screen that gave us a choice to either start in 'safe mode' or 'repair computer'. We opted to repair computer and did a system restore dating back a week. The problem was instantly fixed and it was all pretty easy.